Transformation from squared integral to double integral
for context, I saw a friend of mine did this, is he correct?
$$[T(1/2)]^2 = 4(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx)^2$$
which becomes:
$$[T(1/2)]^2 = 4(\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2}dx dy)$$
Is what he did correct? if it is correct can someone explain to me why

Hint: In the second integral pull out $e^{-y^2}$ and use Fubini’s theorem.

@kieransquared can you elaborate?

Pay careful attention to what’s treated as constant. Once you pull out $e^{-y^2}$ from the $x$ integral, the $x$ integral is constant with respect to the $y$ integral. You should be able to figure it out from here.

I'll assume $T$ is positive for simplicity, but it's not a necessary condition and the negation of this will also hold true.
$$T(\frac{1}{2})=2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx$$
Given that the variable of integration doesn't matter, as it will disappear once we evaluate at the endpoints, we can equivalently say
$$T(\frac{1}{2})=2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}dy$$
If we combine them multiplicatively, we get
$$[T(\frac{1}{2})]^2=\left(2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx\right)\left(2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy\right)$$
We know that integration is linear, so constant multiples can be factored into or out of the integral. For our integral in $x$, observe that the whole integral in $y$ is constant. There are no $x$ terms anywhere in the $y$ integral, so we can treat it just like any other constant.
$$[T(\frac{1}{2})]^2=4\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\left(\;\int\limits_{y=0}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}dy\right)dx$$
Now see that we are multiplying our $y$ integral by a function of $x$, which is constant in the $y$ world. We can treat it as such and factor it into the $y$ integral, since that is still inside the $x$ integral and won't change as a result of the $y$ integral.
$$[T(\frac{1}{2})]^2=4\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\;\int\limits_{y=0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}e^{-y^{2}} dy\right)dx$$
Equivalently, we could have treated the $x$ integral as a constant first, and the $y$ function as a constant second, meaning we also have
$$[T(\frac{1}{2})]^2=4\int\limits_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(\;\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}e^{-x^{2}} dx\right)dy$$
Both orders are correct, and the second order is identical to what your friend produced. He is correct.
